# Kubernetes: call cronjob via rest call

Tags: spring-batch, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have java spring application runing into kubernetes cluster. The batchs implemented via Spring batch and scheduled via cronjobs defined in kubernetes helm charts. Is there any rest api to launch via rest call a batch directly from a postman for example ?